# Language, Proof, and Logic: Problem 11.26 How to give both possible translations of an ambiguous English sentence into FOL?

Tags: logic

In the book "Language, Proof, and Logic" there is a problem 11.26 about translating ambiguous sentences.

Given an ambiguous sentence in English, we should provide two translations, one for each interpretation. Though this is not stated, I believe these are sentences for which we can have a "strong" or a "weak" interpretation. If the "strong" interpretation is true, then the "weak interpretation is also true.

Out of five such sentences, I believe I may have correctly translated three (and I show these below), but I am not sure. There aren't solutions for these problems.

**My question is how to translate the following two sentences into FOL:**

**1. Cube a is not larger than every dodecahedron.**

I see only one interpretation: An object a that is a cube is not larger than every single dodecahedron.

¬∀x (Dodec(x) → Larger(a, x))

What is the other interpretation?

**2. (At least) two cubes are between (at least) two dodecahedra.**

Not sure what the two interpretations are here.

**As examples of what I mean, here are three sentences that I believe I translated correctly** (my level of confidence that they are totally correct isn't very high though).

**Example 1. Every cube is between a pair of dodecahedra.**

**Strong:** There is a pair of dodecahedra and every cube is between this one pair.

∃y ∃z ∀x (Cube(x) → Between(x,y,z))

**Weak:** For every cube there is some pair of dodecahedra that the cube is between.

∀x(Cube(x) → ∃y ∃z Between(x,y,z))

**Example 2. Every cube to the right of a dodecahedron is smaller than it is.**

**Strong:** There is a dodecahedron and every cube to the right of it is smaller than it.

∃y (Dodec(y) ∧ ∀x ((Cube(x) ∧ RightOf(x, y)) → Smaller(x, y)))

**Weak:** For every cube, if the cube is to the right of some dodecahedron then the cube is smaller than the dodecahedron.

∀x ∀y ((Cube(x) ∧ Dodec(y) ∧ RightOf(x, y))  → Smaller(x, y))

**Example 3. No cube is to the left of some dodecahedron**

**Strong:** There is a dodecahedron and no cube is to the left of this dodecahedron.

∃x (Dodec(x) ∧ (∀y (Cube(y) → ¬LeftOf(y, x))))

**Weak:** If an object is a cube then there is no dodecahedron that the cube is to the left of.

∀x (Cube(x) → ¬∃y (Dodec(y) ∧ LeftOf(x, y)))

Comment: you leave out any question except in the title, and I'm a bit unsure what you are asking. I agree with your comment about strong / weak, if that helps at all? not good with logical notation

Comment: I've appended the question explicitly: how to translate questions marked as 1. and 2. into FOL?

Comment: The strong reading of your 1st question is ∀x (Dodec(x) → ¬Larger(a, x)), and its weak reading is ¬∀x (Dodec(x) → Larger(a, x)) which is entailed by the former. For your 2nd question, you need to learn how to express at least two cubes in FOL like ∃x∃y(Cube(x)∧Cube(y)∧x≠y)...

Comment: So the strong reading is that "Every object that is a dodec has the property that a is not larger than it", and the weak reading is that "It is not the case that every dodecahedron has the property that a is larger than the dodecahedron", or in other words "There exists a dodecahedron such that a is not larger than the dodecahedron". Even now I find the ambiguity in the English sentence extremely subtle, to the point where I can't even really see it though I know its there now.

Comment: The subtlety is this. In the strong interpretation, we are saying that when we consider each dodec, a is not larger than it. In the weak interpretation, we are saying that for some dodec, cube a is smaller than it. In the weak interpretation we are saying that cube a may be larger than some dodecs, but not all of them. So tricky.

Comment: you got it and you'd probably never feel the subtleness had you didn't do this exercise... As the ancient [Shrangama sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html) once oded: *Extremely subtle, the Adana consciousness. Makes patterns of habit that flow on in torrents...* Our numerous habits were formed subltly without any of our own notices...

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because not a logic homework forum.